# Bootstrap for email styling with Rails 5 in API mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, actionmailer, premailer

I have a Rails 5 API app. I'd like to be able to send styled emails using Bootstrap, but after adding `gem boostrap` to my Gemfile and running bundle install I get this error:

```
 7:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000555adc2497f8> (NoMethodError)
```

What do I have to do to so I can use the bootstrap gem in my API app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those still looking into this question

You will have to uncomment "require 'sprockets/railtie'" from your application.rb file.

Then add manijest.js file in 'app/assets/config/manifest.js' and link your directories in that file

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

For more info, you can check out the [rails asset pipeline documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this that did not involve using the `bootstrap` gem.

Using the `premailer` and `premailer-rails` gems I was able to inline the bootstrap styles by including a CDN link in the header of my mailer's HTML template.

Comment: that might slow down the process of sending emails considerably, if done at scale.